Crashlytics request finished with status code 403 and doesn't appear on firebase dashboard
I finished setting up my firebase project and implement some of the features including FCM and crashlytics but when I'm trying to set up my first crash so dashboard can detect it, nothing happens and when I'm checking my application Logcat something like this error appears first run of application after crash:


I'm sure everything is done as it must, step by step according to documents. But what's wrong? what's the solution?
PS: FCM working perfectly so project is set correctly. but crashlytics is not working.
some more data:
build.gradle (app)
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
    namespace 'xxxx'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'xxxxx'
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 35
        versionCode xx
        versionName "xxxx"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        buildConfig = true
        lint {
            checkReleaseBuilds = false
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_14
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_14
    }
}

dependencies {
//    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.9.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:24.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:21.0.1'
    //Play Services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0'
//
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
 //some more implementations

}

build.gradle(project)
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.7.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.7.3' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '3.0.2' apply false
}

google-services.json:
all the numbers are matching firebase console
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "xxxx",
    "project_id": "xx-xxx-xxx",
    "storage_bucket": "xx-xx-xxx.firebasestorage.app"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:xx:android:xx",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "xx.xxxx.xxx"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "xxxxx-xxx"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}

